# Quickest way to check an array of classed for an item?

Tags: php

I have a class with values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [val] => one
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [val] => two
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [val] => three
        )
)
```

What is the quickest way to search this array to see if there is an item with id = 2? I know this will work:

```
$hasTwo = false;
foreach ($arrayItems as $arrayItem) {
    if ($arrayItem->id == 2) {
        $hasTwo = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($hasTwo) {
    // do what I wanted to do...
}
```

Is there no easier way that requires less code that can do the same?

Comment: This question is offtopic as it asks to improve a working code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense friday troll, monday troll, ...

Comment: Reason --> to write awesome code?

Comment: Awesome code is far from your idea on it. There are multitude of criteria but for some reason PHP users know only one - code size.

Comment: Reason is quite weak anyway. To take a random block from your code and ask to shorten it can occupy yourself for ages... I doubt it will do any good though

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$hasTwo = array_filter(
    $arrayItems,
    function($value) {
        return $value->id == 2;
    }
);
```

but you'll need to test which is the faster, and the answer is probably your original code